# Замедлялся поиск файлов в папках после обновления Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

после последнего обновления windows 10 очень замедлялся поиск файлов в папках, а до этого все быстро работало. как исправить это? И еще до обновления он автоматически искал файлы после ввода слова в поле поиска и не нужно было нажимать Enter или кнопку для поиска. Подскажите как исправить это? Надеюсь доходчиво объяснил.

Comment: > до обновления он автоматически искал файлы после ввода слова в поле
 поиска и не нужно было нажимать Enter 
Это новая функция в windows, не баг. На счёт поиска - у вас могла выключиться индексация файлов, которая ускоряет поиск https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/4520146/fix-problems-in-windows-search

Comment: @Стас Спасибо за ответ, а как убрать эту новую функцию, где нужно прожимать Enter?Мне больше старый подход нравился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как убрать эту новую функцию, где нужно нажимать Enter?

Решения через настройки я не нашёл, но есть программа на github, способная вернуть старый поиск. Автор предупреждает:

> Защитник Windows определяет этот файл как содержащий
>   Trojan:Win32/Ditertag.B. Это ложный положительный результат, и он
>   находится в процессе разрешения с помощью Microsoft (идентификатор
>   отправки b50a9288-ef88-4127-8863-a1e84cfc25c4).

Из-за этого Google Chrome блокирует загрузку этого файла, но Microsoft Edge - нет (на других браузерах не проверял).

И так, чтобы вернуть старый поиск в Windows 10 нужно:

1. Скачать программу mach2 в соответствии с разрядностью своей системы
   (x86 или x64) https://github.com/riverar/mach2/releases
2. Распаковать архив с программой в любую папку
3. Запустить командную строку **от имени администратора** и перейти в
   папку с программой (`cd "путь до папки"`)
4. Выполнить команду: `mach2 disable 18755234` (если командная строка
   запущена **не** от имени администратора вы получите ошибку *unknown
   error*)
5. Перезагрузить компьютер

**Внимание!!!** После выполнения данной команды у вас выключится поиск и меню пуск (компьютер можно выключить нажатием `Alt + F4`), после перезагрузки эти функции снова будут работать, и у вас вернётся старый поиск.

Также, изменения, внесённые данной программой, могут быть отменены установкой какого - либо из накопительных обновлений.